# Magento issuing ALTER TABLE command at every page load multiple times

Tags: mysql, magento, alter-table

I'm trying to track down anything I can to optimize the performance of my Magento site. I've just noticed that a certain SQL command is running UP TO 91 times on a page:

```
ALTER TABLE `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive` MODIFY COLUMN `is_edited` smallint NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT ''
```

Does anyone have an idea what this is or why this is or most importantly., how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting similar issue and fix which I have applied is as follows :

This module is particularly active on any order events please disable it totally if you can.

if you look at : /app/code/core/Enterprise/SalesArchive/etc/config.xml

there is a cron job that and many event that is the main cause this to happend

please disabled all the event listening in the config.xml of this module.

---

**Please try to comment ( If you have this file )**

app/code/community/MDN/AdvancedStock/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php
line 69 to 79 in this way

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
   {
   parent::_prepareColumns();

$this->addAfterColumn('increment_id', array(
           'header'=> Mage::helper('Organizer')->__('Organizer'),
'renderer' => 'MDN_Organizer_Block_Widget_Column_Renderer_Comments',
'align' => 'center',
'entity' => 'order',
'filter' => false,
'sortable' => false
),'real_order_id');

/*$this->addAfterColumn('payment_validated', array(
 'header'=> Mage::helper('AdvancedStock')->__('Payment validated'),
 'width' => '40px',
 'index' => 'payment_validated',
 'align' => 'center',
 'type' => 'options',
 'options' => array(
 '1' => Mage::helper('purchase')->__('Yes'),
 '0' => Mage::helper('purchase')->__('No'),
 ),
 ),'status');*/


 //raise event to allow other modules to add columns
Mage::dispatchEvent('salesorder_grid_preparecolumns', array('grid'=>$this));

}
```

---

**Another option to fix this issue is as follows**

Basically we get two flags which might be added to a app/etc/local.xml. Assuming a site is hosted on multiple frontend web servers, update scripts should only be processed on one of them. Setting

```
<global>
    <skip_process_modules_updates>1</skip_process_modules_updates>
</global>
```

on all but the “master” web server will avoid race conditions between the hosts.

There is a better way to avoid race conditions for processing setup scripts, and that is by not allowing any web servers at all to process setup scripts.
This is how it works. Instead of setting the skip_process_modules_updates flag on all but one server, it should be set to a true value on all hosts. Then the setup process can be triggered by a short shell script.

It works for me. See If that helps to you.